# Javascript add and multiple

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is have this problem answered (A+B+C) * 4

I don't know how to get it to work right with my current code right now, it is set up like this:

```
<script>
(function () {
    function calculateScoring(man, boy, girl) {
        man = parseFloat(man);
        boy = parseFloat(boy);
        girl = parseFloat(girl);
        return (man + boy + girl * 4);
    }

    var Scoring = document.getElementById("diveScore");
    if (Scoring) {
        Scoring.onsubmit = function () {
            this.score.value = calculateScoring(this.man.value, this.boy.value, this.girl.value);
            return false;
        };
    }
}());
</script>
```

Comment: Did you ever learn `PEMDAS` for Maths class? Programming languages tend to use a similar order of operator precedence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple operator precedence.

```
return (man + boy + girl * 4);
```

should be

```
return (man + boy + girl) * 4;
```

JS follows operator precedence similar to Math. Your code returns `man + boy + (girl * 4)` instead of `(man + boy + girl) * 4`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 return (man + boy + girl) * 4;
```